# ThymeLeaf: How can i pass a model attribute sent from my server to JS from Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am send Sending a list from server to thymeleaf through model attribute

```
friendsOnlineModel.setFriendsOnline(defaultFriendRequestService.getFriendsOnline(user) == null ? Collections.EMPTY_LIST : defaultFriendRequestService.getFriendsOnline(user));

    chatModel.setChats(defaultChatService.getUnreadChats() == null ? Collections.EMPTY_LIST : defaultChatService.getUnreadChats());

    model.addAttribute("friends_online", friendsOnlineModel);

    model.addAttribute("chats", chatModel);
```

I dont want to display them straight in an "li" tag, but rather pass it to a js function which displays them. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this.  You could use [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining), and add the data directly into your page. Similar to the example:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var fiendsOnline = [[${friends_online}]];
    var chats = [[${chats}]];
</script>
```

Then you can deal with them in javascript however you want.

Or, instead of putting these attributes on the model, you can add them to a different controller method annotated with `@ResponseBody`.  Then you call that method using ajax, and Spring will return your object as JSON.

Comment: Thanks very much it worked, the @responsebody method is slow, because i want it on startup(on page load).